# TFS 2010 after successfull build running a script

Tags: tfs, build, post-build

I am trying to build my solution at the TFS2010, after successfull build, I am trying to make  TFS2010 run another application, like VS Post-build event.

It can be possible? and How can I make It?

Comment: To be a useful question, you should try it out first, state what you have tried, and what didn't work for you, and more information about what you are trying to build.

Comment: I am actually tryin dbdeploy using DBDeploy.Net 2 I am configured it as runing after build and chack db version and migrate new version. This process will be automatic on Dev envarment by each check-in. so I could not find any place to write script. How Can I run dbdeploy.Net after successfully build on TFS side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need to do is add an activity to your process template for your build.

In your build configuration, the Process area allows you to specify the template that will be used to execute the build.  This XAML file should already be source controlled in your TFS project.  You can create a new XAML based on your current one, or if you have already created your own just check out your XAML and edit it.

I'm not familiar with DBDeploy or how to invoke it, but if it has command-line arguments you can likely add an InvokeProcess activity to your build workflow and execute a Powershell command script to do what you need to add after the build.

Comment: Thank you for help, I solved my problem using TFS Build Extensions.

Comment: InvokeProcess was what I was looking for. Now I just have to figure out how to use it!